# How and why this can be used with class...?

Tags: java

we have a class having a property.... in that class i have a `inner class` with having same property name...
if i print that property in `inner class` then it will show the value of inner class..
i am surprised by the to class property  of `outer class`.. because its use `this` with class name....i don't know why and how  `this` can be behave  as `static` .
**Example**

```
public class Super {

int x=10;
class nest
{
    int x=20;
    public void show()
    {
        int t=Super.this.x;
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
public static void main(String a[])
{
    Super n=new Super();
    nest s=n.new nest();
    s.show();
}
}
```

Comment: `nest s=n.new nest();` this actually compiles? wow :D I have thought that only the outer class can create instances of an inner class.

Comment: This prints "10", like I would expect.  Why do you expect something different?

Comment: @ZeissS: The inner class has package visibility, so anyone in the package can access it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, access. but not instantiate. But I guess I was wrong here.

Comment: it is just a synax choice? Here **Super.this** just translates to its outter object's reference

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `OuterClassName.this.fieldname` is used to refer to a field or method in the outer class instance **from within the inner class**. I dont see why you would consider it behaving as static.